# Auto Log Wordcount from Docs to Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs, word-count

Having a lot of trouble finding this and as a very beginner programmer, I can't quite troubleshoot my way through this.

What I want to do:

Automatically log the word count of a google doc in a google sheets cell.

The code I've been playing with to try and make it happen that is probably super wrong:

```
function countWords() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openByURL().getBody().getText();
    var punctuationless = doc.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()"?“”]/g," ");
    var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
    var count = finalString.trim().split(/\s+/).length; 
    return count;
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is, in sheets, set it up so there's a column with links to google docs and be able to just put in a function that will return the wordcount from that doc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can not create a custom function to do this, as reading another document requires authentication. You can however do this with an in-sheet button which runs the script.*

#### More Information:

As per the [documentation on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), it is not possible to run methods which require authentication such as `DocumentApp`:

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data

As a result, you will instead have to manually run the script - but this can be done from a button in the Sheet.

#### Code:

Assuming that you have the Document links in column `A` and wish for the word count to be in column `B` (starting in row 2):

```js
function countWords() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var linkRange = ss.getRange("A2:A");
  
  try {
    linkRange.getValues().forEach(function(cell, index) {  
      if (cell[0] == "") {
        throw "Cell A" + (index + 2) + " is empty"
      }
      let doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(cell[0]).getBody().getText();
      let count = (doc.match(/\b\S+\b/g) || []).length;
      ss.getRange(index + 2, 2).setValue(count);
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
}
```

**Rundown of this function:**

- Open the sheet containing the document links (remember to change the sheet name!)
- Get the range of links down column `A`
- Loop through each link and obtain the Document's text
- Obtain all instances of *word-boundary/non-whitespace/word-boundary* in the document, puts them all into an array, and gets the length of the array.
- In this step, if the document is empty, then an empty array is given
- Sets the cell in column `B` adjacent to the link to the result of the count.
- This is all wrapped inside a `try/catch` so that the script stops execution when it reaches an empty cell in column `A`.

#### Assigning to a Button:

Now, you can create an in-sheet button which will run the script whenever you click it.

1. Go to the `Insert > Drawing` menu item and create a shape; any shape will do, this will act as your button.
2. Press `Save and Close` to add this to your sheet.
3. Move the newly-added drawing to where you would like. In the top-right of the drawing, you will see the vertical ellipsis menu (`⋮`). Click this, and then click `Assign script`.
4. In the new window, type `countWords` and press `OK`.

Now, each time you click the button, the script will run.

#### Visual Example:

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)